# Format ASP .Net Input Tag Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

Using ASP .Net Core (Version 2.2, NON-MVC)

I have a database field (Car) which contains text, in HTML format.

I am using an ASP .Net "Input" Helper Tag to display the data (read only) on a webpage.

```
<input asp-for="Car.Description" asp-format="" disabled class="form-control" />
```

I would like to display the data as Html.Raw, but am unsure how to do so.

I originally thought I could do something like this (use Html.Raw), but this throws an exception:

```
<input asp-for=@Html.Raw(Car.Description) asp-format="" disabled class="form-control" />
```

I then thought the "asp-format" field might have some usable options, but I don't see any.

```
<div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label asp-for="Car.Description"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-10">
            <input asp-for="Car.Description" asp-format="" disabled class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

End result is that I would like to have the  display "raw" HTML on the screen.

Thanks

Comment: what specific error does the Html.Raw throw?

Comment: `<input asp-for=@Html.Raw("Car.Description") asp-format="" disabled class="form-control" />  
  


InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ExpressionMetadataProvider.FromLambdaExpression<TModel, TResult>(Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression, ViewDataDictionary<TModel> viewData, IModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the field as read only, you may not even need the "input" helper tag. Just displaying the data in the div should work.

Remove the input helper and just display the text in the div as follows:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-2">
        <label asp-for="Car.Description"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
        @Html.Raw(Car.Description)
    </div>
</div>
```